# Git says branches are up to date when they are not

Tags: git

I have two branches: 1.0, and IE-Fixes. I have no uncommitted changes in IE-Fixes or 1.0. Whenever I try to merge IE-fixes into 1.0, I keep getting told that it is up to date, but I know by looking at them in a browser that the two branches are different.

How can I merge the branches when Git is saying they're the same and won't do so?

Comment: From which branch are you starting the merge?

Comment: Sorry - trying to merge IE-fixes into 1.0

Comment: So you need to make sure you have both branches up to date, the go to 1.0 and merge IE-fixes.